# Knockout BindingHandler & jquery ui spinner - delay on user input

Tags: jquery-ui, knockout.js

I've got a knockout viewmodel that contains an observable array of "Weight" like the following

```
var Weight = function(item){
var self = this;
self.weight = ko.observable(item);
self.lbs = ko.computed({
    read: function () {
        return Math.floor(self.weight() / ozInLbs);
    },
    write: function (newValue) {
        self.weight((((newValue * ozInLbs) + parseFloat(self.oz())).toFixed(3)*1000)/1000);
    },
    owner: self
});
self.oz =  ko.computed({
    read: function () {
        return ((self.weight() - self.lbs() * ozInLbs).toFixed(3)*1000)/1000;
    },
    write: function (newValue) {
        self.weight(((newValue + (self.lbs() * ozInLbs)).toFixed(3)*1000)/1000);
    },
    owner: self
});
```

}

w/ the following html

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td>lbs</td>
        <td>oz</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: weights">
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" data-bind="spinner:lbs" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" data-bind="spinner:oz" /></td>
</tr>
```

idea is that as I increase oz w/ the spinner - once 16 oz are hit - lbs increases by one and oz back to zero. This is working in the following jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ajwaka/Ps36B/

Now - as these are essentially text inputs' I'd like to allow a user to add 1.25 lbs - and have it automatically update the inputs to LBS - 1 and OZ = 4

The issue is - as soon as I get to 1.2 - everything is updating automatically and I get Lbs = 1 and Oz = 3.  How can I get this to delay for 1/2 a second just when a user inputs the value 1.25 I get lbs = 1 and oz = 4?

To be clear - I want to keep the instant update happening when using the spinner - but delay for user input if the user is entering the value via the keypad/keyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily achieve this with [Throttle's](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/throttle-extender.html). A throttle stops updates from actually happening until the value has been at rest for the specified amount of time. Here is [your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ps36B/3/) with a 500ms Throttle.

The code looks like this:

```
self.lbs = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            return Math.floor(self.weight() / ozInLbs);
        },
        write: function (newValue) {
            self.weight((((newValue * ozInLbs) + parseFloat(self.oz())).toFixed(3)*1000)/1000);
        },
        owner: self
    }).extend({ throttle: 500 });
```